# How should I deal with two google-services.json files?

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-plus-signin

I am developing a android application which deals with google+ sign in and real time data base of firebase to add this features.

We need to make project and authenticate at google cloud console and fire-base console.

Now the problem is I have 2 google-services.json file which need to be placed by same name and same place at android studio my Project-app folder if I place both it deflects each other.

What should I do now?

Comment: Why do you have **two json** files? AFAIK, only one json file is all you need per project.

Comment: how can it perform for both google sigin in and firebase database ??

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `FireBase console` you need to turn on Google signing in Firebase Authentication and then generate a json file.

Comment: Do that json file will be use for both googlesiginign and real time database  ?? as i am done with successfull sigining google+ with github source code project

Comment: I am not sure what code u have implemented..but google signin code is available at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin..

Comment: or else open the 2 json files in notepad++ and try to compare and merge the code(which is not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

1. Add Firebase to your Android project.
2. Add the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Google Sign-In to your app-level build.gradle file:

   `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'`
3. If you haven't yet connected your app to your Firebase project, do so from the Firebase console.
4. If you haven't yet specified your app's SHA-1 fingerprint, do so from the Settings page of the Firebase console. See Authenticating Your Client for details on how to get your app's SHA-1 fingerprint.
5. Enable Google Sign-In in the Firebase console:
   a. In the Firebase console, open the Auth section.
   b. On the Sign in method tab, enable the Google sign-in method and click Save.

After this follow the step by step procedure of enabling google sign in as mentioned in the above link.

> The reason behind having same file name is both the services are part of google services and you dont need two different Google services setupt for single project.